# influxdb 2.0 certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1129)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, influxdb, influxdb-2

When I'm trying to delete or insert data into influxDB 2.0 I suddenly started getting this error.

It was working without any issue earlier

Does anyone know how to fix it

````
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1129)```
````

Answer (score 3):

Fixed this issue.
Fix was adding this line when initializing the influxDB client

`ssl_ca_cert=certifi.where()`

```
client = influxdb_client.InfluxDBClient(
    url=os.getenv("URL"),
    token=token,
    org=os.getenv("ORG"),
    ssl_ca_cert=certifi.where()
```